# Magento duplicate products from one DB to another

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a Magento based website where I have over 1000 products.

I'm trying to duplicate **only the products** to a new magento site.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to do it? I'm not entirely sure which tables holds which data as there are 337 tables.

Thanks,

Comment: A miniumum of 5 tables and an index or three. In the EAV system rows become columns identified by on-the-fly generated keys which makes direct SQL access to extract data, especially full product information, pretty complex. Relational database operations you're used to implementing for this don't really apply. Export and reimport as mentioned below is the best way of handling it as you're letting Magento take care of the cascade of self-joins necessary to access EAV stored data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento allows you to export and import products. In the admin section go to System -> Import/Export then select Export to dump out your existing set of products in CSV format.

If you are changing Magento version, then create a dummy product and produce a dump from the newer version Magento. Compare both the CSV formats and modify your product data to fit the newer version format if you have to. Then import the CSV into the newer Magento installation.